# Из-за какой библиотеки возникает ошибка from models.VAE import VariationalAutoencoder?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd

from models.VAE import VariationalAutoencoder
from utils.loaders import load_model, ImageLabelLoader
```

В книге *generativnoe-glubokoe-obuchenie* в блокноте *03_06_vae_faces_analysis.ipynb* есть код, строка которого не определяется. Все библиотеки из **requirements.txt** установлены.

Как решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 0):

Разделительная пустая строка установлена не случайно, а в соответствии с соглашением.

Сначала идут встроенные или установленные модули, затем свои собственные, реализованные в соседних файлах.

В главном PyPi есть [models](https://pypi.org/project/models/) и [utils](https://pypi.org/project/utils/), но скорее всего это не то, что вам нужно.

В книге ничего об этом не говорится? В предыдущих главах ничего подобного не реализовывалось?

Мне кажется, что да (книгу я не читал, если что). Но в [репозитории, который предположительно относится к материалам из книги](https://github.com/davidADSP/GDL_code) я вижу папки `models` и `utils` со всеми необходимыми файлами типа `VAE.py` и `loaders.py`.

Проверьте папку, из которой запускается ноутбук.

[image: репозиторий]

Comment: действительно, из-за невнимательности упустил это, причем это БЫЛО описано в книге, но не придал значения. спасибо